# Ruby is unable to find a gem or "require" file

Tags: ruby, rubygems

A simple Ruby code

```
require 'rest-client'
server = "http://localhost:3000"
response = RestClient.get(server + "/posts.json")
```

It throws an exception

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- rest-client (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/alex/app1.rb:41:in `<main>'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

`rest-client gem` is installed. And I'm using Ruby `1.9.3` and not `1.9.1.` Even more, there is no ruby `1.9.1` installed on my machine.

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
```

What is that happening and do I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby 1.9.3 (and 1.9.2) stores gems in the 1.9.1 folder (I know, this is awkward).

If the project uses Bundler, make sure to list the dependency in the bundle `Gemfile`.
Also, make sure the gem exists in that specific Ruby version.

```
$ gem list
```

Maybe you installed it for Ruby 1.9.2 and you are now using 1.9.3.

Comment: I run it as standalone ruby file, not as a Rails project. How do I know if I installed it for Ruby 1.9.2?

Comment: Run `$ gem list` and check the output. If you are not sure, run `$ gem install rest-client` again.

Comment: By the way, I'm using Sublime text 2 to run it (Ctrl+B).

Comment: Use the console, chances are Sublime Text is falling back to your system ruby.